# Spring form does not submit when hidden field is added

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a the following form in a jsp file :

**form.jsp**

```
<table>
<form:form modelAttribute="command" action="daoselect.app">
    <tr>
        <td>Store this data</td>
        <td><form:checkbox path="query"/>
    </tr>
    <form:hidden path="list"/>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

This is what my app-servlet.xml file looks like:

**app-servlet.xml**

```
<bean name="/daoselect.app" class="de.xx.DAOSelectController">
    <property name="commandClass" value="de.xx.DAOSelectCommand"/>

    <property name="xmlservice" ref="GuestBookDataXML"/>
</bean>
```

This is what the **DAOSelectCommand.java** file looks like

```
public class DAOSelectCommand {

private boolean query = false;
private List<GuestBookData> list;

public List<GuestBookData> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<GuestBookData> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public boolean getQuery() {
    return query;
}

public void setQuery(boolean query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public DAOSelectCommand() {

}


/*This constructor is used before loading the jsp file to add the list data to the hidden field*/
public DAOSelectCommand(List<GuestBookData> t) {
    this.list = t;
}
```

The problem that I have is that the onSubmit function of the DAOSelectController class is not executed when I add the `<form:hidden path="list"/>` field and the browser is trying to load the daoselect.jsp file insetead. If I remove this hidden field then the onSubmit function is executed normally.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the generated `<input type=hidden>` element is at an “unexpected” place in the DOM tree; the browser is trying to make sense of this, but ends up relocating the element to outside the table, which puts it outside the form. This then makes all sorts of things go wrong with the interpretation of the following `<input type=submit>`. Working out exactly what happened to get everything into that state is going to be tricky, and isn't really worthwhile since the fix is to move the `<form:hidden>` *up* to beside the `<form:checkbox>`, which is *inside the `<tr>`*, and to move the `<form:form>` *outside* the table. This puts the elements in the proper DOM contexts for those sorts of things element, stopping the browser from having to work nearly so hard to figure out what things mean (and encouraging it to get it right…)

```
<form:form modelAttribute="command" action="daoselect.app">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Store this data</td>
        <td><form:checkbox path="query"/>
            <form:hidden path="list"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

Also, always close `<td>` and `<table>` elements; it avoids all sorts of problems.

Comment: I see what you mean but although I made the modifications you suggested the onSubmit function is still not executed . :(

Comment: @Stefanos Then use your browser's dev tools to see what sort of DOM tree you've actually ended up with, and don't just show us the inputs to the processing. (Also, what versions of things are you using?)

Comment: I used the chrome inspector and the page source looks exactly like what I expected ... Do you mean something different ? I am using Spring 2.5.6